# On-shell renormalization (Schwartz Quantum Field Theory Equation (18.48))

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization, self-energy

I have a question about how, in section 18.3.2 in Schwartz's quantum field theory, he goes from equation (18.47) to (18.48) using Pauli-Villars regularization. It comes down to showing that to leading terms in $m_\gamma$,
$$-\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\int_0^1 dx x \ln \frac{x\Lambda^2}{m_P^2(1-x)^2+xm_\gamma^2} = \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2}-\frac{9}{4}-\ln\frac{m_\gamma^2}{m_P^2}\Big).$$
It seems like he is using the fact that
$$\ln\frac{x\Lambda^2}{m_P^2(1-x)^2+xm_\gamma^2} = \ln \frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2}+\ln \frac{x}{(1-x)^2 + xm_\gamma^2/m_P^2}.$$
Then, it seems as though he is evaluating the integral
$$\int_0^1dx x\ln \frac{x}{(1-x)^2 + xm_\gamma^2/m_P^2}$$
and only consider certain terms. However, this does not quite give Schwartz's result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot the infrared-divergent term (the integral at the bottom of your question is infrared-finite). Start with formula (18.47) in the book of Schwartz and remember that $p^2=p \! \! \!/ \cdot p \! \! \!/$, which has to be taken into account when you compute $\frac{d}{d p  \! \! /} \Sigma_2(p \! \! \! /)$! Then you will find that the divergent formula (18.46) has to be replaced by the infrared-regulated equation

$\frac{d}{d p \! \! /} \Sigma(p \! \! \! /)|_{p \! \!/ =m_P} = \frac{\alpha}{2 \pi} \left( \frac{1}{2}  \log \frac{\Lambda^2}{m_P^2} +\frac{5}{4} -\int_0^1 dx \frac{2 x(2-x)(1-x)}{(1-x)^2+x m_\gamma^2/m_P^2} \right)$

Computing the remaining integral (and discarding terms vanishing in the limit $m_\gamma \to 0$) leads to formula (18.48).